# Opened empty txt file with notepad after write text to it

Tags: python, subprocess, pysimplegui

I have PySimplegui and I've written code that creates and write text to .txt file and after that is done I call subprocess to open that file with notepad, but file is empty.

I've using .close(), but seems that has no effect. When I go to check that file there is text, but when I open that file in GUI  (written; PySimpleGUI) it's empty.

```
list_output = open(Path + '/list.txt', 'w')

# script.py writes some data to txt file and this part of code works fine...
subprocess.Popen(['python', Path + '/script.py'], stdout=list_output) 

list_output.close()

open_list = subprocess.Popen(["notepad", Path + "/list.txt"])
```

Comment: subprocess.Popen() doesn't actually run the process.  You have to call `communicate` on the result of subprocess.Popen().

Comment: What's in `script.py`? Make sure your code constitutes a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @saquintes is right but the proper fix is to use `subprocess.run()` instead which does wait for the process to complete etc.

Comment: subprocess.run() makes that working. Thanks

Comment: @tripleee now it open notepadd ok, but pysimplegui form is stuck and get "not response" until I close notepadd and open gui form again. It writes text.txt fine etc...

Comment: Your question could have been more explicit about this requirement. Performing any blocking action from within a GUI's event loop will obviously block the event loop, too. It's really not clear what exactly you are trying to accomplish here. Just `Popen` will allow Notepad to run in parallel with your Python script. So I guess you will want `subprocess.run()` for the first subprocess, and `subprocess.Popen()` for the second one.